# Open url in pop window when browser window is close

Tags: javascript

I m trying to open url in pop window when browser window is close  below script i m using bt its not working when popup is block in the (Chrome)browser setting

```
<script> var exit=true; window.onbeforeunload = function() {
exit = window.open("#", "name", "width=400, height=300")
}</script>
```

Comment: plz don't do this for a real website. it just annoys users.

Answer (score 6):

That is the whole purpose of popup blocker, it is a browser setting and I don't think you can override it

Answer (score 0):

try with disabling the popup blocker